# How to deserialize an array with leading label in front without using wrapper object?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

My web service (WS) receives an HTTP POST request and JacksonJsonProvider is deserializing incoming body object into JSON string. The DTO is simple:

```
public class SettingDTO {
   private String key;
   private String value;
   ...
}
```

The WS signature looks like this:

```
@Post
Response saveList(List<SettingDTO> list);
```

The WS is awaiting an array in the input. Example:

```
{
    "settings": [
        {
            "key": "key1",
            "value": "val1"
        },
        {
            "key": "key2",
            "value": "val2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This results in an exception. **Jackson does not know how to handle the leading "settings" label. If I try it without the label, just a plain array, it works well.** But the requirement is set to use it the way it is.

One solution I know is to use a wrapper object, another DTO. **I wonder if this could be solved without an extra wrapper?** Maybe an annotation will do the job?

After deserialization, I want to end up with the populated `List<Setting> settings ...`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways can achieve this. But if you don't want to use an extra wrapper class, one way is to read the inner JSON string first, then deserialize it to `List<SettingDTO>` as follows:

**Code snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();      
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
String settingsStr = root.get("settings").toString();
List<SettingDTO> settings = mapper.readValue(settingsStr, new TypeReference<List<SettingDTO>>(){});
System.out.println(settings.toString());
```

**Console output**

> [SettingDTO [key=key1, value=val1], SettingDTO [key=key2, value=val2]]

---

BTW, if you have tried to add `@JsonRootName(value = "settings")` to class `SettingDTO`, AFAIK, it doesn't work for JSON array!